# Is Amazon Elastic Beanstalk The Correct Environment For Someone That Needs To Do A Lot Of A/B Testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I hoping I can get some insight into the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment before investing considerable time into switching projects to the AWS platform.

I am an entry level web developer so I do "A LOT" of A/B testing on very minor changes. It is my understanding that I have to upload an entire package or application to AWS ESB. Is that correct or can up change a single file, upload it, and test it?

I have a handful of media sites (php / MySQL) that occasionally go viral so I like the idea of auto scaling.

If I have to upload an entire application each time, what strategy do you recommend for someone that needs to be able to do regular small A/B tests of their code?

Thanks for you help!
Todd

Answer (score 0):

How often and how large are the changes done for the A/B testing? Per https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/update-an-app/ the application does need to be re-deployed if the source code changes.

If you want the ability to edit files `live` in production; that...is not exactly best practice. In fact, it is very frowned upon. Best practice is to make the chance in DEV, push the application to an automated process that deploys the application. Refer to logging and monitoring tools to watch production. A/B testing is very easy to rationalize using CloudWatch logs and a visualizer like grafana.

A couple other options: configure Lightsail, Heroku, or other PaaS providers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The project I'm looking to move to AWS is part web application and part website. The web application will not change too frequently, but it will be used to dynamically create webpages (.php files) and update the contents of several .txt files.  So the web app creates new webpages (/pageName4338.php) and updates existing files (/cat/content.txt) each time it is used. Will that work on AWS EBS?

Comment: Given the information available, I would deploy the web application to BeanStalk. Have the output placed onto an EC2 instance/s. The EC2 instances would host the web pages. Group the EC2 into an Auto Scaling Group and place them behind a load balancer. Bonus: Load balancers can be used to direct a %age of users to site `B` during A/B testing. 

Side note: EBS stands for `Elastic Block Store` when speaking about AWS services. BeanStalk does not have a shorthand that I know of.

Comment: I created a AWS ENv diagram here for you to make it easier to visualize: https://cloudcraft.co/view/59f79902-49f1-4a1f-a094-322691b66575?key=vHtnMcNgKSoXRPIlboEtlw&interactive=true&embed=true